# exit button not working properly

Tags: android

I have developed app I want to write code for exit button.I was searching code for exit button and I got it from internet.Now the exit button code is working properly but when i open app from the emulator it is opening directly 3rd activity. Splash screen and second activity are unseen i don't know where i am going wrong

This is the code for exit button

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

can you please tell me code where

**my manifest file is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.finan"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"

android:anyDensity="true"/>
<application
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/dollar"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.finan.Splashscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.finan.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.finan.second"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.finan.Monthc"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What code format you used ?

Comment: i have copied and pasted the code from manifest file

Comment: Exit the while application or move to another activity.

Comment: i need to exit the app

Answer (score 0):

I know what kind of problem your getting , where ever you are using the code to exit you application just add this code so that your activity get RESTARTED!

```
public void onPause()
{
  super.onPause();
  finish();
}
```

and if you have used any static variable , just set them NULL at the press of EXIT BUTTON!
and try to finish your activity after intent!

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: if i write the finish(); after the startActivity(intent) it is going to last activity my app is not closing

Comment: where should i write the pause() method

Comment: You should write it after the onCreate method inside your class

Comment: it will finish your paused activity so that when you launch you app again it will show the launcher activity

Comment: it is giving the following errors  Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
 - Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
 - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete

Comment: ok you must have miss something show me the entire code and mark it where you getting error i'll do it!

Answer (score 0):

you need to learn  `Activity Stack`

What actually you are trying to do is *imitating* the same action that we get on click of *Home button* i.e to send the activity to background

your app is behaving normally according to code.. when you **click the exit button** it send the app to background like **home action** and and it **resumes** from where it was actually left i.e third activity in this case.

I usually kill tha app at such times, instead of making it complex
using following snippet

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Just add it to you Exit button click..

For detailed knowledge of Activity Stack read activity stack at [google docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

or ADD `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` to make it happent he way you are doing  to clear all the activities in the current stack

Comment: android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());  i have tried this but only the current activity is getting closed not the entire app.so i am trying intents

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the activities alive for you..
I mean call finish() after going to new activity all the time..

Comment: add this Flag to clear all the activities  to your code
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: There is some change. Before when i used to click on exit button it used close but when again open or launch app it used to open directly third activity but when i used    "intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);" in onclick method it is opening the second activity i am missing the splash screen

Comment: for this I would rather suggest you to call finish() every time you open a new activity this one will actually make sure that only one activity will be active at any instance.. and after doing so you will not miss anything..